# How to wipe sprites, that they don't repeat

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning to code in pygame. And I've faced with problem, that I can't wipe previous sprites. I mean image is just extending along the screen. How can I move a sprite instead extend it?

```
def check_edges(self):
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right: #if alien has caught up the right edge of the screen
        return True
    elif self.rect.left <= 0: #if alien has caught up the left edge of the screen
        return True

def update_aliens(custom_settings, aliens):
    check_fleet_edges(custom_settings, aliens)
    aliens.update()

def check_fleet_edges(custom_settings, aliens):
    for alien in aliens.sprites():
       if alien.check_edges():
           change_fleet_direction(custom_settings, aliens)
           break

def change_fleet_direction(custom_settings, aliens):
   for alien in aliens.sprites():
       alien.rect.y += custom_settings.fleet_drop_speed #fleet_drop_speed is the value of whole fleet's speed
   custom_settings.fleet_direction *= -1 #change direction of fleet's moving
```

My drawing code is right here:

```
def update_screen(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens, bullets, rockets, stars):
   screen.fill(custom_settings.bg_color)
   for bullet in bullets.sprites():#возвращает список спрайтов в группе
       bullet.draw_bullet() 
   for rocket in rockets.sprites():
       rocket.draw_rocket()
   stars.draw(screen)
   aliens.draw(screen)
   spaceship.blitme()
   pygame.display.flip()
```

And this is my main loop:

```
while True:
    gf.check_events(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, bullets, rockets)
    spaceship.update()
    bullets.update()
    rockets.update()
    gf.update_ammunition(bullets, rockets)
    gf.update_aliens(custom_settings, aliens, screen)
    gf.create_fleet(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens)
    gf.starsky(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, stars)
    gf.update_screen(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens, bullets, rockets, 
        stars)
    clock.tick(FPS)
    print(clock.get_fps())
```

[This is how they move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA2vA.png)

[image]

Comment: Look at the part of the code where you are drawing the aliens on the screen (you should add this part in your question). You are just drawing the aliens at each position on the screen, but you never delete from the screen the aliens you have drawn the previous mainloop iteration. If you add the drawing part of the code in your question, we can help you better.

Comment: I've done. I hope that you will able to help me

Comment: It seems you are filling the screen with white color each iteration, so my initial guess was wrong. The drawing part seems correct. Try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. I think the problem is somewhere else, in a part you have not shown. Maybe in the `update()` method of your alien Sprites, or in the `create_fleet` function.

Comment: Does `custom_settings.bg_color` have an alpha-channel that's making it transparent?  This would stop the screen erasing on the `screen.fill()`.

Comment: custom_settings.bg_color is just self.bg_color = (255, 255, 255). I am just beginner in python and I don't quite understand what did you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that sprites spawned infinitely. I should just limit quantity of aliens

```
def create_fleet(custom_settings, screen, spaceship, aliens):
   alien = Alien(custom_settings, screen)
   number_aliens_x = get_number_aliens_x(custom_settings, alien.rect.width)
   number_rows = get_number_rows(custom_settings, spaceship.rect.height,    alien.rect.height)
   for row_number in range(number_rows):
       for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
           if len(aliens) <= 48:
               create_alien(custom_settings, screen, aliens, alien_number, row_number)
           else:
               aliens.remove(alien)
```